# Can't accept multiple command line arguments and assign to variable

Tags: c

I am learning C and I am not used to pointers and the way C handles strings. I am trying to create a program that accepts multiple command line arguments and assigns them to variables so that I can later use them. I can get the program to accept the first argument and assign it as a int. But when I try to accept the second argument I get a SEGMENTATION FAULT. I have tried testing by removing the second variable (service) and then assigning port to argv[2] and it doesn't work. It is something about accepting the second argument that the compiler does not like but I am not able to figure it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    char service = argv[2];   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `char service = argv[2];`, you are assigning a char pointer to a char. You know `argv` is a char pointer array, because you define it as `char *argv[]`. Fix by just adding `char *service = argv[2];`

So your rewritten code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Requires more arguments");
        return 1;
    }

    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    char *service = argv[2];   
    printf("%s", service); //From edit
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to add a check for the value of `argc` (i.e. `argc >= 3`), since it will seg fault if there aren't three arguments.

#### Edit (response to comment):

To print the service, use:

`printf("%s", service);`

The `%s` specifies you will print a string of characters (`char *`) and you simply use `service`, because you need to specify the pointer.

#### Edit 2:

If you don't add `#include <stdlib.h>`, you will receive something along the lines of "warning: implicit declaration of 'atoi' is invalid in C99", which may also produce an error depending on your compiler settings.

Comment: Awesome. I missed that I believe. I just tried to do a printf("%s", service); and the compiler gives me segmentation fault on that printf statement. And as far as the arguments argv[0] is the files name. So I don't need that part, just what the user adds when running it.

Comment: Also, always compare `if (argc < 3) { /* handle error */ }`. You can use `!= 2`, etc.., but *validate* the availability of arguments. You can even use successive *ternary* operators providing a default for each argument if you like.

Comment: Updated my solution with those considerations BrianJarcus, and good addition @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Thank you David C. Rankin. I had that part of my original code but I slimmed this code down to just the issue I am running into. Matt Goodrich, I can print the port, another issue I have is printing the service.

Comment: @MattGoodrich Much better. Always try and incorporate all necessary validations in your code (even for examples). Remember, when answering questions on SO, you step into the role of teacher. No slacker profs here...

Comment: I will make sure to include everything next time. Also, your last edited code is what I have right now, and it produced a segmentation fault for the printf statement.

Comment: this would not cause a segmentation fault. argv[0] is the program name. The incorrect char type will cause a compiler warning. My guess is that not enough args wre passed in.

Comment: @prm100 this is during compile that it produces this error.

Comment: The error produced is because you do not have `#include <stdlib.h>`. I have added this to my sample code.

Comment: Hmm, weird because I have that included. My code is exactly like yours.

Comment: You have `#include <stdio.h>`, not both `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: My code is on another computer or I would copy it here. But it does have both. It also has <string.h> but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Program received seignal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. In msvcrt !_beginthreadex () (C:\Windwos\system32\msvcrt.dll). BUT, if I run the program anyways, it works as intended. I have tried the code you made earlier today. I thought I was doing it right, but I was getting this error so I thought it wasn't working. Not sure why I am getting this error but it appears to be working.

Comment: ^ Please share how you are compiling and running your program.

Comment: I am using Codeblocks and using the mingw compiler all on default settings. Not sure what to show.

Comment: Typically you will compile from the command line with something like `gcc test.c` and execute with `./a.out these are args`, but it sounds like you are using your IDE (Codeblocks) for these processes. In my opinion these go beyond the scope of your question and justifies research on your end to verify your IDE is configured correctly. Then ask another Stack Overflow question if you still have problems, indicating it's a Codeblocks/mingw issue. I have tested the code in my solution and it works as intended.

Comment: That is true. I am still learning the way C works. I am more of a Python user which everything is easier. Thank you for your help.